# Efficient architecture/tools for implementing async web API

Tags: rest, asynchronous, database-design, architecture, microservices

Consider an event-driven microservice based web application that should have some async web APIs. AFAIK the suggested way to achieve async http request/response is to respond each API call with a say `202 Accepted` status code and a location header to let caller retrieve the results later.

In this way, we have to generate a unique ID (like `uuid` or `guid`) for each request and store the id and all related events in the future in a persistent storage, so the API caller can track the progress of its request.

My question is how this API layer should be implemented considering we may have tens or hundreds of thousands of requests and responses per second. What is the most efficient architecture and tools to make such an API with this load?

One way could be storing all the requests and all related events in both database and a cache like redis (just for a certain limited time like 30 minutes).
Is there any better pattern/architecture/tools? How big companies and websites solved this issue?
Which database could be better for this scenario? (MongoDB, MySQL, …)

I really appreciate any useful answer specially if you have some production experience.

Answer (score 1):

very valid question! In term of architecture or tools point of you should check out [**zipkin**](https://zipkin.io/), which is an open distributed tracing system tried and tested by Twitter and especially if you have a microservice architecture, It is really useful to track-down all your request/response. It also includes Storage options include in-memory, JDBC (mysql), Cassandra, and Elasticsearch.

If you are using spring-boot for your microservices then it is easily pluggable.
Even if you are not totally convinced with Zipkin, architecture is worth looking into. From Production experience,  I have used it and it was really useful.

Comment: Thank you @Yogendra for your answer. Can zipkin be used by web API client for getting the results of their past requests? I thought it has been used for logging and analyzing requests for administrative purposes.